# Heapster : Unauthorised, grafana: unauthorised

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, unauthorized, heapster

I deployed heapster+grafana+influxdb combination. And i got the result like this

> ```
> $kubectl cluster-info
> Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443
> Heapster is running at 
> https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-
> system/services/heapster/proxy
> monitoring-grafana is running at 
> https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-
> system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy
> monitoring-influxdb is running at 
> https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-
> system/services/monitoring-influxdb/proxy
> ```

But when i tried to access these services in web browser i get the following error:

> ```
> {
>   "kind": "Status",
>   "apiVersion": "v1",
>   "metadata": {
> ```

```
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Any help friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I exposed both grafana and heapster using Nodeport.
I added the following instruction under spec of grafana and heapster yaml files(services)

```
 type: NodePort
```

Then I checked the services list by using the following command.

```
kubectl get services -n kube-system
```

It showed the expose port of grafana and heapster somthing like this.

```
80:32068/TCP for heapster <br>
80:32230/TCP for grafana<br>
```

Then I could access both grafana and heapster with cluster_IP:port

For ex:

for grafana - http://192.168.99.100:32230/

for heapster -http://192.168.99.100:32068/api/v1/model/namespaces/default/pods/

Comment: the problem is that you no longer benefit from cluster autthentication, so while ok for dev playground, should not be used like this in production

Answer (score 1):

Well, your browser is not authorised to access kubernetes API. The simplest approach to this would be to run `kubectl proxy` that will authenticate to the cluster and proxy API requests from localhost to your kube API. That way you will be able to access API on 127.0.0.1 without credentials on the browser side.

Comment: Actually i already ran kubectl proxy. But still its not working.

Comment: did you try something like `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/metrics` after starting `kubectl proxy`

Comment: yeah i did.I get the following error. "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",

Comment: what do you have in `kubectl -n kube-system get svc`? is heapster / grafana on it ?

Comment: Both heapster and grafana are there.

Comment: hey I could access grafana dashboard in the way you said(by using the proxy). I used the command http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy/

Comment: I am still not able to access heapster api.